# Cypher Neo4j - Rank similar entities based on same relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In image you see nodes P which are of the same type, all of them have relations to nodes of type C. This is just a generic view with not to many details but all entities has parameter ID. Lets say that I have P1 with distinct relationship patterns i.e to C1-C5... How can I then fetch similar entities of type P that has same relationships and rank on the amount of similar relationships...

Result I would like to have is based on that I have P1 with known HasProperty to C1 a ranked result as:

P2, has 4 similar relationships and also having C1
P3, has 3 similar relationships and also having C1
P4, has 2 similar relationships and also having C1

[image: Neo4j]

Thanks!

Comment: what does "similar relationship" means ? Is it they have a relationship in common with same type and same hasProperty ID ?

Comment: Hi, yes exactly and then rank the result based on the number of "similar relationships" (with same type and same hasProperty ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following graph :

```
CREATE (p1:P {id: 'p1'})
CREATE (p2:P {id: 'p2'})
CREATE (p3:P {id: 'p3'})
CREATE (c1:C {id: 'c1'})
CREATE (c2:C {id: 'c2'})
CREATE (c3:C {id: 'c3'})
CREATE (c4:C {id: 'c4'})
CREATE (p1)-[:RELA {hasProperty: 1}]->(c1)
CREATE (p1)-[:RELA]->(c2)
CREATE (p1)-[:RELA]->(c3)
CREATE (p1)-[:RELA]->(c4)
CREATE (p2)-[:RELA {hasProperty: 1}]->(c1)
CREATE (p2)-[:RELA]->(c2)
CREATE (p2)-[:RELA]->(c3)
CREATE (p2)-[:RELA]->(c4)
CREATE (p3)-[:RELA]->(c2)
CREATE (p3)-[:RELB]->(c3)
CREATE (p3)-[:RELA]->(c4)
```

[image]

You can return, given p1, for each of p2, p3 two list of booleans, one for same relationship type, one for same hasProperty value :

```
MATCH (n:P)-[r1]->(c)<-[r2]-(other)
WHERE n.id = 'p1'
WITH other.id AS otherId, 
collect(r1.hasProperty = r2.hasProperty) AS sameHasProperty, 
collect(type(r1) = type(r2)) AS sameType
RETURN *

╒═════════╤═════════════════╤═════════════════════╕
│"otherId"│"sameHasProperty"│"sameType"           │
╞═════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│"p3"     │[]               │[true,false,true]    │
├─────────┼─────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│"p2"     │[true]           │[true,true,true,true]│
└─────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Then, you can give a score for true or false in each collection.

Let's say similar hasProperty scores 2.0 and similar relationship type scores 1.0 :

```
MATCH (n:P)-[r1]->(c)<-[r2]-(other)
WHERE n.id = 'p1'
WITH other.id AS otherId, 
collect(r1.hasProperty = r2.hasProperty) AS sameHasProperty, 
collect(type(r1) = type(r2)) AS sameType
RETURN otherId, (size([x IN sameHasProperty WHERE x = true])*2.0 + size([x IN sameType WHERE x = true])*1.0) AS score
ORDER BY score DESC

╒═════════╤═══════╕
│"otherId"│"score"│
╞═════════╪═══════╡
│"p2"     │6.0    │
├─────────┼───────┤
│"p3"     │2.0    │
└─────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Thanks, Christophe... This solves my scenario. Lets say that Relationship (r1 and r2 in your example) does not have any property but C-nodes has one called Id ... Is it then the same setup but I can skip first collect-statement "collect(r1.hasProperty = r2.hasProperty) AS sameHasProperty" or ?

Comment: Well, since the pattern on the C node is matched already, they will for sure have the same c.id